# How to shift a string to the right by n characters

Tags: python

I was practicing coding and found this exercise on the internet:

Enter a string s and an integer n in the two lines respectively, and define a function to move the string s to the right by n bits, and to the left when n is a negative number.

If s is an empty string '', output '' regardless of n.

Sample input:

```
s ='123456'
n=3
```

Sample output:

```
Output result: 456123
```

I did this so far:

```
def shiftall(s, n, left, right):
    while left <= right:

        if s[left] < 0 and s[right] < 0:
            left += n


        elif s[left] > 0 and s[right] < 0:
            s[left], s[right] = \
                s[right], s[left]
            left += n
            right -= n


        elif s[left] > 0 and s[right] > 0:
            right -= n
        else:
            left += n
            right -= n


def display(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print(s[i], end=" ")
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = str(input('s='))
    n = int(input('n='))
    shiftall(s, 0, n - 1)
    display(s)
```

But getting error and can't tackle it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    shiftall(s, 0, n - 1)
TypeError: shiftall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'
```

Any suggestions? EDITED MISTAKE OUTPUT*

Comment: Use `__name__`.

Comment: it's `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Just a suggestion, another approach to this is: ```s = "123456" \
n = 3 \
n = n % len(s) \
while n: \
    s = s[-1] + s[:-1] \
    n -= 1 \

print(s)```

Comment: You can achieve the shifting more concisely using slicing: `s[-n:] + s[:-n]` is your shifted string.

Comment: Just a clarification, you are *not* shifting a string by *bits*, but simply changing the character's *position* in the string.  Each character in the ASCII string is 7 bits.

Comment: Per the edited question: The `shiftall` method takes **4** parameters, you are only passing in 3.  TBH, the error is quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

It is `__name__` and not `name`

Also you can do :

```
s = s[n:] + s[:n]
```

to shift the string.

Comment: Sorry i included wrong error, now u can check it normally

Answer (score 0):

`if name == "__main__":` should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

`__name__` is a special built-in python variable corresponding to the name of the current module.

EDIT: New error:

`shiftall(s, 0, n - 1)` is only provided 3 arguments:

- s
- 0, and
- n-1

Did you forget the last argument, or did you mean `shiftall(s, 0, n, 1)`?

It looks like you are providing n as 0 and instead providing it as the value for 'right'

Comment: sorry i included the wrong error, now u can check exact error

Comment: @GreatDreamer answer updated

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are the parameter `left` and `right` for? All the information is in the number `n`. Moreover, strings are immutable, so you cannot assign string indices like `s[foo] = "b"`. You will have to return a new string from your function:

```
def shiftall(s, n):
    n %= len(s)  # make sure you are within the bounds of s
    return s[n:] + s[:n]
```

Then you can reassign your `s` with the function result:

```
s = "123456"
n = 3
s = shiftall(s, n)
print(s)
# 456123
```